# Jquery Mobile in visualforce - simple page transition error

Tags: visualforce, jquerymobile

The following is a simple jquery mobile page in visualforce. The page renders ok, but on swiping (or clicking -- whatever you choose to trigger the transition event with) the page crashes, consistently generating two error messages in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MenuButtonRounded is not defined
>  Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: scaleImage is not defined

Any suggestions would be most appreciated --  Im stuck as to why this might be happening and how to resolve it.

```
> <apex:page doctype="html-5.0" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"
> standardStyleSheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">
> <html> 
>     <head> 
>     <title>My Page</title> 
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"
> />
>     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
>     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
> </head>  <body>    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
>  
>     <div data-role="header">
>         <h1>My Title</h1>
>     </div><!-- /header -->
>  
>     <div data-role="content">   
>            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
>           <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
>           <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
>            </ul>
>     </div><!-- /content -->   </div><!-- /page -->   <div data-role="page" id="page2">
>  
>     <div data-role="header">
>         <h1>My Title</h1>
>     </div><!-- /header -->
>  
>     <div data-role="content">   
>            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
>                <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
>           
>            </ul>
>     </div><!-- /content -->   </div><!-- /page --> 
> 
> 
> <script>
>     $("#page1").on("swiperight",function(event){
>         $.mobile.changePage( "page2");      // this is where my error occurs!
>     });
> 
> </script> </body> </html> </apex:page>
```

Comment: I pursued this and the issue definitely had something to do with use of jqm in vf. Same markup worked fine outside of vf, so was correct forum to post to. Resolved through use of a different boilerplate.

Comment: For reference - these two errors appear as a direct result of using the applyHtmlTag to false and showHeader attribute to false. something in the base VF page still tries to call methods that are no longer loaded.  I'd suggest this is very relevant to the VF section of stackoverflow. The only way to resolve was to set showHeader back to true, which is obviously not desirable.